# How can I set the width of a text based in the flexible row above in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this card with a flexible Row that is setting the width size of the card and beneath it I have a text field that should only be as large as the Row above, but as the text is bigger, it streches the Card.

How can I fix the width of the Text to be the same as the flexible Row without jumping line with \n?

```
 Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0, right: 12),
                          child: Image.asset('assets/card_recommendation.png'),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                              child: Text(
                                  'Elimine',
                              style: TextStyles.paragraphSmall12DarkerGreyMedium,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ]
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 24),
                    child: Text(
                      'Zerando a anuidade do seu cartão de crédito',
                      style: TextStyles.paragraphSmall12DarkerGreyMedium,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [FittedBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Uehk3_wlY)
If the text is too large, FittedBox will automatically decrease the font size so that it fits inside the Card's space.